# Kendo UI Grid - Deleting a row, an error occurs but the row is still removed from the grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI Grid MVC. When a row is deleted from the grid, and an error occurs on the server, an error is displayed to the user (based on what is stored in ModelState), as it should, but the row is still removed from the grid when it shouldn't be removed. How can I get prevent Kendo from removing the row from the grid on a server error?

Comment: Use custom delete button for your kendoGrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As workaround you can try to catch grid dataSource `error` event and use `canelChanges()` method if it occured:

```
...
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    ...
    .Events(events => events.Error("onGridError"))
)
```

And in JavaScript:

```
function onGridError() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.cancelChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jaroslaw Koriczak's answer is technically accurate, however he is accessing the grid inefficiently.
Kendo events send the grid datasource as 'this' in them when they call their functions.

```
...
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
...
    .Events(events => events.Error("onGridError"))
)
```

This part is correct, however the event should be this:

```
function onGridError() {

    this.cancelChanges();
}
```